# Как добавить копию элемента несколько раз? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно добавить в dotsContainer копию элемента с id="dot" несколько раз, но мой код добавляет только одну копию, а потом, как я понимаю, просто ее обновляет. Что мне делать ?

```
const copyDots = document.querySelector("#dot").cloneNode(true);

for (let i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    dotsContainer.append(copyDots);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
  const copyDots = document.querySelector("#dot").cloneNode(true); 
  copyDots.id = 'dot_' + i;
  dotsContainer.append(copyDots); 
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]